# Hg: how to get diff of two different files?

Tags: mercurial, diff, tortoisehg

I'm sorry if it's odd question. I have a mercurial repository. Is it possible to get a diff of two different files from some revision by `hg`? For example, there is a revision

```
revision xxx
    - file1
    - file2
```

How I can get a diff of `file1` and `file2` by standard hg command or any extensions?

Thank you.

**UPD**
I would like something like this:

```
hg diff -r xxx file1 file2
```

Than I will have all changes between two files of same revision.

Comment: Why don't you use `diff`?

Comment: @wRAR I tried to find how I can but nothing.

Comment: Mercurial is not the tool to use here. Just fire up any file difference tool and use it to compare the files. Mercurial has a per-file focus with these commands.

Comment: @hcp  I meant `diff`, not `hg diff`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially I read your question differently, but your comment made clear that you are asking about the differences between *two files of the same revision*. That's nothing where the VCS has any stakes in.

You simply can use (on *nix systems) the diff command:

```
diff FILE1 FILE2
```

If you need the difference of the files at particular revisions, of course you can use mercurial before that in order to get to that:

```
hg update -rXXX
```

or even to see the difference of FILE1 at revision XXX compared to FILE2 at revision YYY (but beware, it changes the working dir content; make sure to undo the revert afterwards):

```
hg revert -rXXX FILE1
hg revert -rYYY FILE2
diff FILE1 FILE2
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply .But I think it is not what I want. The command get a diff for file 1 and file2 between TWO REVISIONS. I would like to get difference between TWO FILES of one revision. I'm sorry if It's not clear. I want to get all changes (diff) of two files in same revision.

Comment: Sorry, indeed I read it differently. Reworded my answer accordingly